# Как сделать так, чтобы если объект на Canvas переместить на место второго объекта, тот сместится и освободит место для вставки первого объекта

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть 2 объекта в виде плитки на Canvas. Растянуты по всей длине, перемещение осуществляется только по вертикали. Как сделать так, чтобы если взятый объект для перемещения поставить на место другого объекта, тот сместится ниже или выше и освободит место для текущего объекта?
На данный момент в проекте, который сделан при помощи паттерна MVVM, есть главное окно, где создан канвас, отдельный контрол с плиткой и отдельный класс на перемещение объектов, который наследуется от класса Thumb

```
public class Move : Thumb
{
    public Move()
    {
        base.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(Move_DragDelta);
    }

    void Move_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Tile tile = this.DataContext as Tile ;

        if (tile != null)
        {
            double minTop = double.MaxValue;
            double top = tile.Top;
            minTop = double.IsNaN(top) ? 0 : Math.Min(top, minTop);
            double deltaVertical = Math.Max(-minTop, e.VerticalChange);
            tile.Top += deltaVertical;

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Какое может быть решение для реализации такой задачи?

Comment: У вас реально только два объекта, или впоследствии будет больше? Вы случайно не изобретаете drag-and-drop в list view?

Comment: VladD, В последствии будет больше. Нет, это не list view. У меня нет задачи создать, что-то в виде списка или таблицы. На Canvas полноценные графические объекты, которые потом будут дополняться новыми функциями.

Comment: Ну, в WPF элементами list view тоже могут быть полноценные графические объекты, это ж не WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой пример у меня получился
xaml:

```
    <Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Image Canvas.Top="0" Source="Resources\1.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="{Binding ElementName=mainCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
           MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Image_MouseMove"></Image>
        <Image Canvas.Top="100" Source="Resources\2.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="{Binding ElementName=mainCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
           MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Image_MouseMove"></Image>
        <Image Canvas.Top="200" Source="Resources\3.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="{Binding ElementName=mainCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
           MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Image_MouseMove"></Image>
        <Image Canvas.Top="300" Source="Resources\4.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="{Binding ElementName=mainCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
           MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Image_MouseMove"></Image>
        <Image Canvas.Top="400" Source="Resources\5.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="{Binding ElementName=mainCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
           MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Image_MouseMove"></Image>
    </Canvas>
```

Код C#:

```
    private Image draggedImage;
    private Point mousePosition;
    private double currentLeftPos;
    private double currentTopPos;
    private int current_index;
    private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = e.Source as Image;
        if (image == null)
            return;

        var grid = image.Parent as Canvas;

        if (image != null && grid.CaptureMouse())
        {
            mousePosition = e.GetPosition(grid);
            draggedImage = image;
            currentLeftPos = Canvas.GetLeft(draggedImage);
            currentTopPos = Canvas.GetTop(draggedImage);
            current_index = mainCanvas.Children.IndexOf(draggedImage);
           
            Panel.SetZIndex(draggedImage, 1); // in case of multiple images
        }
    }

    private void Image_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        mainCanvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();

        if (draggedImage != null)
        {
            // получить координаты мыши 
            System.Windows.Point position = e.GetPosition(mainCanvas);

            //проверим что картинка требует сдвига
            if (currentTopPos < position.Y && currentTopPos + draggedImage.ActualHeight > position.Y)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(draggedImage, currentLeftPos);
                Canvas.SetTop(draggedImage, currentTopPos);//вернем элемент на место
                
                Panel.SetZIndex(draggedImage, 0);
                draggedImage = null;
                currentLeftPos = 0;
                currentTopPos = 0;
                current_index = 0;

                return;
            }

            double new_TopPos = currentTopPos;

            //сдвинем все обьекты
            int tmp_index = 0;
            foreach (Image image in mainCanvas.Children)
            {
                //                    double tmp_left = Canvas.GetLeft(image);
                double tmp_top = Canvas.GetTop(image);

                if (image.Equals(draggedImage))
                    continue;

                if (tmp_top + image.ActualHeight < position.Y)
                    continue;//оставляем без изминений
                else
                //нашли место для передвигаемого элемента
                if (tmp_top < position.Y && tmp_top + draggedImage.ActualHeight > position.Y)
                {
                    //подготовим последовательность
                    tmp_index = mainCanvas.Children.IndexOf(image);
                    if (currentTopPos < position.Y)
                        tmp_index--;
                    
                    Canvas.SetTop(draggedImage, tmp_top);
                    new_TopPos = tmp_top + draggedImage.ActualHeight;
                }
            
                //смещаем все другие элементы
                Canvas.SetTop(image, new_TopPos);
                new_TopPos += image.ActualHeight;
            }
            mainCanvas.Children.Remove(draggedImage);
            mainCanvas.Children.Insert(tmp_index, draggedImage);

            //теперь надо удалить пустое место
            //сдвинем все обьекты
            new_TopPos = 0;
            foreach (Image image in mainCanvas.Children)
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(image, new_TopPos);
                new_TopPos += image.ActualHeight;
            }
            
            Panel.SetZIndex(draggedImage, 0);
            draggedImage = null;
            currentLeftPos = 0;
            currentTopPos = 0;
            current_index = 0;
        }
    }

    private void Image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draggedImage != null)
        {
            // получить координаты мыши 
            System.Windows.Point position = e.GetPosition(mainCanvas);

            var offset = position - mousePosition;
            mousePosition = position;

        //    Canvas.SetLeft(draggedImage, position.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(draggedImage, position.Y);
        }
    }
```